# Pass a React constant to useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs

I need to pass the data from const of GraphQL useQuery to hook as following:

```
const { loading: loadingData, data: timeWindowsData } = useQuery(din_times_for_rep);


useEffect(() => {
    setStartTime(moment(timeWindowsData.din_times_for_rep[0].val).format(format));
  }, []);
```

It keeps saying that `din_times_for_rep` is "undefined". I've tried different ways to pass it as below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setStartTime(moment(timeWindowsData.din_times_for_rep[0].val).format(format));
  }, [din_times_for_rep]);
```

And so on, but no luck. Any advise please?

Upd.

Declared as:

```
let din_times_for_rep = gql` {
        din_times_for_rep {
            id
            name
            val
                }
            }
        `;
```

Comment: is `din_times_for_rep` a prop? Could you try logging it to see what it's value is before the call to the useEffect?

Comment: no, it not a prop, its declared as (added to question part). And I can log the timeWindowsData.din_times_for_rep[0].val in the other part of component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timeWindowsData` isn't populated until the query is complete. Could you try adding a guard to the useEffect call and see if that helps?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!loadingData) {
    setStartTime(moment(timeWindowsData.din_times_for_rep[0].val).format(format));
  }
}, [timeWindowsData, loadingData]);
```

Comment: Sorry if distubing, if you would be so kind to look my another question that is connected with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383667/set-default-value-from-database-to-timepicker-in-react-on-first-load